# referrer URL not being grabbed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, referrer

I am trying to pull the referrer URL, apply a regex to it, and using the result as the value in a textfield. The issue is that the current implementation is not pulling the referrer URL into the textfield, which would come from clicking a link on the previous page, but allowing me to input a value instead. It should automatically populate the textfield with the referrer and allow the user to search based on it (or search manually instead, if they haven't previously clicked a link). The console outputs `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null` for the line `$("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);`, because it's trying to find the second value in the array of the resulting string (meaning there's no referrer URL being pulled). Not sure whats wrong with my logic

**Case 1**

With this logic, it does pull the referrer URL, but does not allow the user to search manually (without a referrer pre-populating the search field)

```
var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
if (encodeID !== null && encodeID.length == 1) {
    $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
} else {
    var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
    var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
    $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
}
```

**Case 2**

With the additional
if statement, it doesnt pull the referrer URL, but does allow the user to search manually

```
var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
    var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
    if (encodeID !== null && encodeID.length == 1){
       $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
    }else if($("#imageid").val() !== ''){
        var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
        var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
       $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
    }
```

The user needs to be able to either click on a referrer URL and have it pre-populate the field, or search manually.

Comment: Just quick side note, there's no need to reassign `regexp` and `encodeID` since they are first assigned outside the `if` statement.

Comment: I know, just been more focused on this annoying little logic issue.

Comment: It appears that the regex doesn't match. Place `console.log(encodeID);` below `var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);` and see what the output is in the console.log

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "search manually". Now the `.referrer` can only be pulled when the user clicks a link to the page, not if they manually type in the URL. I'm not sure, though, if it comes up from a form post... someone check me on that... If you ARE trying to find a referrer from a search request, you might include a hidden field in the search form that sends a "referrer" value with the  POST/GET.

Comment: @micahblu, the regex is working fine. When I run `var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
    var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
    console.log(encodeID);` in the console, I get the value I need.

Comment: @philtune, I mean that the user has to enter the value to search by themselves, without the referrer being set as the textfield value from the referrer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having an issue because arrays are indexed starting from 0, not 1.

```
if (encodeID !== null && encodeID.length == 1) {
    $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
}
```

If `encodeID` has a length of 1, it only has one element, which would be `encodeID[0]`, but you are trying to set the value equal to `encodeID[1]` which would never exist if the array has a length of 1.

Comment: Would a better if statement on that be just `if (encodeID) {...}`?

Comment: I know they start from 0. The array is always going to come through after the regex as `assets/number, number`. I need to be able to pull the value that would be the second `number`.

Comment: @Matt Yes, but your logic is broken. You are testing `length == 1`.. if your regex matches, you will have an array with length 2, not length 1.

Comment: So then this should work: `var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
    var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
    if (encodeID !== null && encodeID.length == 2){
       $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
    }else if($("#imageid").val() !== ''){
       $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
    }`

Comment: Just needed to set the `length` equal to 2. Thanks @BrianGlaz!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to set the array length to 2:

```
var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
if (encodeID !== null && encodeID.length == 2){
   $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
}else if($("#imageid").val() !== ''){
   $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
}
```